# Magento category order on frontend

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I want to change the default order of categories in Magento frontend navigation to order by name. Running Magento 1.5.

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually order the categories in admin by dragging them up and down in the left pane of "Manage Categories" page.

Answer (score 0):

We have been searching on a way to do this also, and ended up doing this:

```
<?php
...
$categories = array(1,3,5); // this holds the category ids you want to show, in the correct order
foreach($categories as $cat){
  Mage::getModel("catazlog/category")->load($cat);
  // Do whatever you want here
}
?>
```

It definitely isn't the cleanest way to achieve what you are trying to do, but just offering you a quick (dirty?) solution.

-Kenny

Comment: This answer is old but for everyone else coming here: Using `load()` is generally slow since it loads all information of the thing you're trying to load (Category, Customer, etc.). It's better to use `Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()` and then `->addFieldToFilter()` to only load what you need, just es Vern Burton said above.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to build the collection first, then sort the attribute

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', '319')->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC');
```

Answer (score 0):

In Admin Panel go to Catalog—>Manage Categories. 
From there you can change categories order by just drag-and-dropping categories right in category tree at the left-hand side of the page.
Good luck!!!